# ASP.NET Core with HttpClientFactory : best practice?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpclient, webservice-client, httpclientfactory

I have an ASP.NET Core application which needs to cyclically call a web service.

I instantiated a `HostedService`:

```
public class MyHostedService : IHostedService
{
    public MyHostedService(IMyWebServiceClient MyWebServiceClient)
    {
      ...
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
       while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
       {
           var result = await myWebServiceClient.CallSomeWebApi();

           await Task.Delay(5000, cancellationToken);
       }

       return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

which calls some function from a `WebServiceClient` class. The class looks like this

```
public class MyWebServiceClient: IMyWebServiceClient
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory;

    public MyWebServiceClient(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        this.httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }

    public async Task CallSomeWebApi()
    {
       using (var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient())
       {
           var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(...);

           var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);
       }
    }
}
```

The startup code is this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ....
    services.AddHttpClient();
    services.AddSingleton<IMyWebServiceClient, MyWebServiceClient>();
    services.AddHostedService<MyHostedService>();
    ....
}
```

Can somebody tell me if it is a good practice calling cyclically

```
var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient()
```

(for instance every 5 seconds)?

Could some side effects occur because of this? I am testing with some Web Server and quite often getting an exception

> The request was canceled due to the configured `HttpClient.Timeout` of 100 seconds elapsing

Could this be caused by the implementation above, or is this definitely a server problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error that you get is because the client API call times out after 100 seconds which is the default timeout so this is probably the server not responding.

It should be fine to create a new `HttpClient` every five seconds. The `HttpClient` instance wraps a pooled `HttpMessageHandler` so it's lightweight (as opposed to the pooled handler). Disposing it doesn't dispose the handler which otherwise could lead to resource exhaustion (client sockets aren't released immediately).

Because the inner handler by default is configured to "refresh itself" at regular intervals to pick up new DNS information you actually don't need to use `IHttpClientFactory` yourself. You can instead inject `HttpClient` directly using a *typed client* as described in [Make HTTP requests using IHttpClientFactory in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests). The article [Use IHttpClientFactory to implement resilient HTTP requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) also explains "best practices" for using `HttpClient` in .NET.

Comment: Thanks for the links, I will take a look. As far as I understand from your answer, the code is robust enough, also for production. Is it possible to change the 100 seconds httpclient timeout?

Comment: @RickyTad Yes, you can set the `HttpClient.Timeout` property to change the timeout. If you use the _typed client_ approach where `HttpClient` is injected into your service constructor you can either modify the `HttpClient` instance in that constructor or when you configure dependency injection by calling `AddHttpClient<MyWebServiceClient>()`. The details are in the linked documentation.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-8.0

I don't think it should use with using according to the doc

Comment: @maxisam Yes, you don't have to dispose `HttpClient`. See [HttpClient and lifetime management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-8.0#httpclient-and-lifetime-management): _`HttpClient` instances can generally be treated as .NET objects not requiring disposal. Disposal cancels outgoing requests and guarantees the given `HttpClient` instance can't be used after calling `Dispose`. `IHttpClientFactory` tracks and disposes resources used by `HttpClient` instances._ As noted disposal is OK. My suggestion is to inject `HttpClient` and not dispose.

Comment: @MartinLiversage thanks for clarify. It was a bit ambiguous from your answer. It will be great if you can update it with your comment : )